# How can I get typeAhead to work everytime on first keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, onkeyup, typeahead

I have a typeAhead function (using the [twitter typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) library) that loads a set of json files when I type the first letter.

These json files are named 'words_a.json', 'words_b.json' etc. They contain every Dutch word that start with the letter A, B, C, etc.

The problems I am facing are:

1) As soon as I type the first character in '#search-box' the focus on the input field is lost. This is due to the '[jquery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)' function. Is there any way to prevent this?

2) I can't use '[jquery.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)' because that will call the json files with every character you type. I only want to call the json file for the first character. It should load all words starting with that character.

3) Another disadvantage of 'jquery.one()' is that as soon as I have found the word I am looking for, I'd like to start searching for a new word. So I remove every character in the input field. However, it won't load another json file for the first character you type, because 'jquery.one()' already fired once and has already loaded a json file. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour and start the function again when all characters are removed from the input field?

Here's my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#search-box').one('keyup', function() {
                    var character = $('#search-box').val().substring(0, 1);
                    var chr = character.toLowerCase();
                    //console.log(chr);

                    $.getJSON('words/words_' + chr + '.json', function(wordsArray){
                        //console.log(wordsArray);
                        $('#search-box').typeahead({
                        name: 'words',
                        //local: [],
                        local: wordsArray,
                        limit: 10
                        }); // close typeAhead function
                    }); // close getJSON
                }); // close search-box keyup function

            $('#search-box').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, value) {
                //console.log(value.value);
                $('#resultaten').append('<a href="#" onClick="speak(&quot;'+value.value+'&quot;, &quot;nl&quot;)">' + value.value + '\
        &nbsp;<img src="img/speaker.png" alt="speaker"/></a><br />');

            }); //close typeahead selected selected function
            $('#search-box').typeahead().destroy();
        }); // close document.ready
</script>


<form class="form-search">
     <h2 class="form-search-heading">Zoek in OpenTaal woordenlijst</h2>
     <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Zoekterm" id="search-box">
     <div id="resultaten"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this:  http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/javascript/suggest1.html

It has a JSON list, and it does use a keypress.  But what good is type-ahead if it is only for the first character?  Say these were names, and you had 10 "Smiths"?  You may want to type "Smith, " to get the first one of them.

In any event, you could always add an "if" statement that counted the length of the value in the textbox.  If `$(this).val().length > 1`, for example, you don't do anything.  `else`, you go forward with your check.